# Can a ratter use your webcam undetected?

Tags: malware, trojan

The Black Hat conference (I wasn't there) had a session on "ratters" (RAT for Remote Access Trojan) who take illicit footage of users (usually female) by hijacking their systems.

The question I have is if this happens on a system or web-cam device that has an "in use" LED on it, is it possible for them to do this without turning on that LED?   On my MacBook for example I would definitely notice the LED.  Many USB cameras have the same thing.

Comment: Yup, it's why I tape cardboard over my lens while not in use :P

Comment: Also, duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/can-webcams-be-turned-on-without-the-indicator-light ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to deactivate the webcam active light. [Here](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/141508/Is+the+iSight+indicator+LED+hardwired+or+can+it+be+circumvented), [here](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/12/18/software-allows-hackers-to-activate-macbook-webcams-without-green-warning-light/), and [here](http://blog.erratasec.com/2013/12/how-to-disable-webcam-light-on-windows.html) all show examples of security researchers doing it.

Comment: Would seem to be very hardware based.  My Macbook should be Ok but not the Windows boxes I have.